# Group by and order by has many through model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Hi I've searched but have not found the way to do this

I have the following models:

```
class Hierarchy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :family
end
```

.

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attributes rank:integer order:integer
  has_many :hierarchies
  has_many :users, :through => :hierarchies
end
```

.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hierarchies
  has_many :families, :through => :hierarchies
end
```

Having the `current_user` I need to get all the other members of his family, grouped by rank and then ordered by the column order.

I would put what I have tried but it's really not that much, and this query is way out of my league.
I'm using postgres.

Comment: Does it have to be a single query?

Comment: @papirtiger not really but preferable if it can be done

Comment: By members of family does it mean that you want to get Family models or members of family means other Users that belong to any Family that the current user belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with the following approach..

We have to update User Model :)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hierarchies
  has_many :families, :through => :hierarchies
  has_many :family_members,
           -> { group('families.rank').order('families.order ASC') },
           through: :families, source: :users
end
```

And then it's very easy to get all members of current user:

`current_user.family_members`

Answer (score 3):

If by family members you mean Family models then you can do something like

```
current_user.families.order(:order).group_by(&:rank)
```

If by family members you mean Users that belong to the same Families as the current user then it gets a little bit more complex, because every user can have many families. That means that every user can have multiple orders and multiple ranks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

For Group By:

```
User.group(:name)
=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" GROUP BY name
Returns an array with distinct records based on the group attribute:
```

For Order By:

```
User.order('name')
=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY name
```

You may want to refer [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html)

Comment: You may search for Order By and Group By on the page, to get more insight.

Comment: This is not what I need I need the results from one table sorted and grouped by fields in other tables